# Why is $helper->getSessionFromRedirect() always returning NULL?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I had this code and it was working fine for months. Suddenly, the production environment stopped working, where `$helper->getSessionFromRedirect()` is now always returning a `NULL` value.

**login form page** (index.php)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(123456, 'a1b2c3d4e5');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://domain.com/login.php');
$scope = array('email');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($scope);

echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login</a>';
```

**login processing** (login.php)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(123456,'a1b2c3d4e5');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://domain.com/login.php');

try {
    # success
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    # when Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    # when validation fails or other local issues
}

if($session) {
    # do something with user data
    $me = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    # redirect to user profile page
    header('Location: http://domain.com/profile.php');
    exit();
} else {
    # $session is always NULL with this code :(
}
```

This **is** working on my test App, but **it's not working** with my production App ID. The only difference between those are, of course, the App ID and Secret ID values. I already made sure I was following the [Facebook instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0). Also, I'm using [Facebook PHP SDK 4](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk)'s last version.

Answer (score 1):

After a long diagnosis, I found out that there was a discrepancy. Since I was using Cloudflare's SSL feature, the original `$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://domain.com/login.php');` request was made with http:80, but the 2nd `$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://domain.com/login.php');` was made with https:443 ... this returns a no match kind of signature to Facebook, which causes the NULL value in the `$session` variable.

**TL;DR** do not mix http and https when making requests to fb.

Comment: Thanks man, this wasn't exactly my problem but it gave me an idea. I was accessing the website without www and facebook redirected to a www. Didn't know it mattered